# Symfony2 Default locale

Tags: php, symfony, request, locale

```
framework:
    default_locale: es
```

When Framework bundle parses config values, `$defaultValue` is set as `es`. The point is when the locale is injected in Router as `DefaultLocale`, value is `en`.

I have been debugging and this value is set from `bootstrap.php.cache` (from Request object), by default `en`.

I have spent too much time trying to resolve this problem but...

Any idea?

Comment: have you cleared the cache? it seems you haven't

Comment: Sure I have... but this is still failing

Comment: Did you enable `translator` under `framework`? Maybe: `translator: { fallback : es }`?

Comment: Yes, I have fallback value under translator...